# How do I get rid of the "shut the screen off" animation on Droid 4?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, motorola-droid-4

I just want the screen to go black. No fade, no "old style tube tv" animation. Is there a way to make it do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Settings > Display > Animation`. I turned mine off and did not see the "old style tube tv" animation any more.

Comment: Nice, thank you! Maybe a follow up question of "how do I turn ONLY the shut off screen and not ALL animations?

Comment: I don't think they went with that much granularity.